# Cryptographic hash chain using recursive method in Java

Tags: java, recursion, hash

I am trying to implement a simple recursive method that produces the hash of a hash `n` number of times which I specify i.e Hash Chain. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class RecursiveHash {
     public static String generateHashChain(int hash_time, String password)  throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
       hash_time--;
       if (hash_time == 1)  
           return Hash.generateHash(password);  
       return generateHashChain(hash_time,password);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(generateHashChain(2,"hello"));
            System.out.println("Test");
            System.out.println(Hash.generateHash((Hash.generateHash("hello"))));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

`Hash.generateHash` is utility method for generating a hash. `hash_time` is the number of times I want hash the hash. However when I test it like above (Hashing two times) I get

```
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
Test
d7914fe546b684688bb95f4f888a92dfc680603a75f23eb823658031fff766d9
```

I expect the answers to be the same. Any ideas about what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(generateHashChain(2,"hello"));
```

This starts the process at `2`.

```
hash_time--;
```

Now at `1`.

```
   if (hash_time == 1)  
       return Hash.generateHash(password);
```

It *is* `1` so only do hash once.

To fix your problem:

```
 public static String generateHashChain(int hash_time, String password)  throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
   if (hash_time == 1)  
       return Hash.generateHash(password);  
   return Hash.generateHash(generateHashChain(hash_time - 1,password));
 }
```